# intelli j" cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I am trying to figure out play framework and I am trying to do some stuff in java. However I defined a superclass with 2 variables as

```
super class Place(int ID, String Nam) {
        }
```

and I want to define "nam" however it doesn't accept as "string" it says cannot resolve symbol
I have done stuff written in previous examples in stackoverflow (invalidating cache and redefining directory to jdk in project structure) but nothing changed, I'm still getting the same error!
Any ideas ?

Comment: What language are you writing your project in?

Comment: `super class Place(int ID, String Nam){}` doesn't look like Java to me. Can you post more code, for example the code that causes the error itself?

Comment: thanks Karol for your help ...what I want to do is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h07rBdzC_Q
which has been built in scala and I am trying to convert that into java
so far what I have written down is...

Comment: package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import views.html.*;

//for rest
import play.api.libs.json.*;


public class Application extends Controller {

 class Place(int ID, String nam) {
        public int ID;
        public String nam;
            super(ID, nam);
            List<Place> list = new ArrayList<Place>();

            Place.add(1,"Paris");
            Place.add(2,"London");
            Place.add(3,"Rome");

    }

Comment: This is not a valid Java code at all. You seem to not know how to define a constructor.

Comment: one thing... as I said I am trying to figure out this play framework and java... it doesn't matter, I am asking for help because I cant solve problem. on the other hand, if you won't help, then don't even try to comment either.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a capitalization problem? Nam vs Nam and String vs string. You have used all of these in your question. Variable and type names are case sensitive.

Comment: String capital, Nam lower..
ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Comment: class Place(int ID, String nam) is not valid java. The parameters (ID and nam) go in the constructor, which you don't have. I'm well aware that String is capitalized, that's the name of the class. The case nam is whatever the programmer chooses, but it has to be consistent.